# How to assign a STANDARD network interface to a compute instance on GCP using terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

When running a terraform template using a STANDARD network like:

```
resource "google_compute_address" "default_standard" {
  name          = "standard-address"
  region        = var.region
  network_tier  = "STANDARD"
}

# Create a virtual machine instance
resource "google_compute_instance" "my_instance" {
  name         = "my-instance"
  machine_type = "e2-micro"  # Free tier instance
  zone         = var.zone
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-11-bullseye-v20230509"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"
    access_config {
      // Public IP
      nat_ip = google_compute_address.default_standard.address
    }
  }
}
```

Gives the error:

Error: Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid resource usage: 'External IP address: 35.211.106.69 has a different network tier STANDARD from the network tier in instance access config PREMIUM.'., invalidResourceUsage

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, the actual instance definition has to include the type of network it will allow:

```
resource "google_compute_address" "default_standard" {
  name          = "standard-address"
  region        = var.region
  network_tier  = "STANDARD"
}

# Create a virtual machine instance
resource "google_compute_instance" "my_instance" {
  name         = "my-instance"
  machine_type = "e2-micro"  # Free tier instance
  zone         = var.zone
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-11-bullseye-v20230509"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"
    access_config {
      // Public IP
      nat_ip = google_compute_address.default_standard.address
      network_tier = "STANDARD"
    }
  }
}
```